# row column heatmap plot with overlayed circle (fill and size) in r

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, heatmap

Here is a graph I am trying to develop:

[image]

I have row and column coordinate variables, also three quatitative variables (rectheat = to fill the rectangle heatmap,circlesize = size of circles,  circlefill = fill color heatmap). NA should be missing represented by a different color (for example gray color).

The following is data:

```
set.seed (1234)
rectheat = sample(c(rnorm (10, 5,1), NA, NA), 7*14, replace = T)

dataf <- data.frame (rowv = rep (1:7, 14), columnv = rep(1:14, each = 7),
          rectheat, circlesize = rectheat*1.5,
          circlefill =  rectheat*10 )
dataf
```

Here is code that I worked on:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(dataf, aes(y = factor(rowv),x = factor(columnv))) +
      geom_rect(aes(colour = rectheat)) +
     geom_point(aes(colour = circlefill, size =circlesize))  + theme_bw()
```

I am not sure if geom_rect is appropriate and other part is fine as I could not get any results except errors.

Comment: all dimensions are proportional to rectheat , it is just for fast sampling? do you want some colors to fill the circles?

Comment: yes, it is just for fast sampling, yes colors need to filled by quatitative variable circle fill and size proportional to circlesize var.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here it is better to use `geom_tile` (heatmap).

```
require(ggplot2)
  ggplot(dataf, aes(y = factor(rowv),
             x = factor(columnv))) +        ## global aes
  geom_tile(aes(fill = rectheat)) +         ## to get the rect filled
  geom_point(aes(colour = circlefill, 
                   size =circlesize))  +    ## geom_point for circle illusion
  scale_color_gradient(low = "yellow",  
                       high = "red")+       ## color of the corresponding aes
  scale_size(range = c(1, 20))+             ## to tune the size of circles
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks agstudy, is there way to proportionally increase circle size they look small in comparison to cell size

Comment: @shNIL increase to look small? sorry I don't understand. the cell size is fixe here , can you rephrase please?

Comment: the circle look small, I want them to be bigger (off-course proportionally)

Comment: @jon  geom_circle? I don't konw yet this one.

Comment: @shNIL what if you change you use shape =21 for geom_point?  geom_point(aes(colour = circlefill, size =circlesize,fill=circlefill),shape = 21)

Comment: @agstudy I tried to add shape = 21, got the error : "Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to shape"

Comment: The error beacuse you put it as an aes. But I have better idea. I use a scale_size, I update my answer.

Comment: @agstudy thanks it is definitely better idea !!! I like scale_size(range = c(5, 15)), which I think reduce the proportions (difference between large or small) but it should be OK as everything is proportional right ??

Comment: @shNIL yes!maybe better scale is something like (min(circlesize ),max(circlesize))...see scales and rescale method to get more fancy scales.

Comment: You might want to consider replacing `scale_size()` with `scale_size_identity()` if you want to use the actual circlesize values in the data frame. Use the argument `guide = "legend"` if you want a legend to be printed (the default is `guide = "none"`).