# How to print R's svg() output instead of writing to file?

Tags: java, r, svg

I am writing a java web-application in which users can select and plot data. The plots are generated with R, and exported to SVG. I was wondering if there is a way to directly return the SVG output stream instead of having to write a file and reading that file in java.

So instead of doing:

```
svg("uniqueName.svg")
plot(someData)
dev.off()
```

and then later having to read the file in Java, I would like to just print the SVG's XML data to the console.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hmmm, it would be nice if one could specify the console-equivalent of "stdout" as the file name, but that doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grid.export` from `fridSVG` package. It produces an SVG version of the **current grid page**. Here an example:

```
library(gridSVG)
library(ggplot2)
qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data = iris, color = Species)

ll <- grid.export()  ## without parameter to save the result a sa list
head(ll$svg)
#   $metadata
#   <metadata xmlns:gridsvg="http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/R/gridSVG/">
#     <gridsvg:generator name="gridSVG" version="1.3-1" time="2013-11-04 13:48:22"/>
#     <gridsvg:argument name="name" value="Rplots.svg"/>
#     <gridsvg:argument name="exportCoords" value="none"/>
#     <gridsvg:argument name="exportMappings" value="none"/>
#     <gridsvg:argument name="exportJS" value="none"/>
#     <gridsvg:argument name="res" value="72"/>
#     <gridsvg:argument name="prefix" value=""/>
#     <gridsvg:argument name="addClasses" value="FALSE"/>
#     <gridsvg:argument name="indent" value="TRUE"/>
#     <gridsvg:argument name="htmlWrapper" value="FALSE"/>
#     <gridsvg:argument name="usePaths" value="vpPaths"/>
#     <gridsvg:argument name="uniqueNames" value="TRUE"/>
#     <gridsvg:separator name="id.sep" value="."/>
#     <gridsvg:separator name="gPath.sep" value="::"/>
#     <gridsvg:separator name="vpPath.sep" value="::"/>
#     </metadata> 
#     
#     attr(,"class")
#   [1] "XMLInternalNodeList" "XMLNodeList"
```

**PS**: this will not work with base graphics , but works with any grid based plot( grid ,ggplot2 ,lattice)...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly this does not work for heatmaps, which are the plots I'm in need off. The solution I went for is using temporary files. It works fine... not as nice though :)

Comment: @mustmiekieke I don't get your point. You can do heatmap with ggplot2 or lattice. For example you can see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097136/row-column-heatmap-plot-with-overlayed-circle-fill-and-size-in-r/14097354#14097354)

Comment: Ah you're right. Maybe I should make the situation a bit clearer: I am making dynamic gene expression heat maps that I later annotate with JQuery to make them interactive. For that I'm using the heatmap() function, because it's easy to use and provides all the necessary additions (like dendrograms and clustering). Because I had to find out how svg() writes heatmaps and base the annotation script on that, I'm reluctant to try another plotting method. I was just wondering if it was possible to capture the output stream of svg(), because I couldn't find a way of doing it in the documentation.